# Nextui-org Card is set to isPressable but I can't add an href to the Card Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components, react-component, nextui

I have this repo here https://github.com/ChristianOConnor/custom-bp-one. It's basically the `npx create-next-app@latest --ts` boilerplate but I'm experimenting with `nextui-org` components. I tried to add `href=https://github.com/nextui-org/nextui` in a card component like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Card
    isPressable
    isHoverable
    variant="bordered"
    css={{ mw: "400px" }}
    href="https://github.com/nextui-org/nextui"
  >
    <Card.Header>First Button &rarr;</Card.Header>
    <Card.Body>Find in-depth information about Next.js features and API.</Card.Body>
  </Card>
</Grid>
```

But when I click on it, I am not redirected to https://github.com/nextui-org/nextui, and I get this in my vscode window when I hover over `href`:

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; isPressable: true; isHoverable: true; variant: "bordered"; css: { mw: "400px"; }; href: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { css?: CSS | undefined; } & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'href' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { css?: CSS | undefined; } & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'. Did you mean 'ref'?ts(2322)
```

So how do I get the `nextui` `Card` component to redirect to a link when clicked? Also can I add a next.js route to the Card component instead of a url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. wrap the card component in a Link component:

```
<Link href="https://github.com/nextui-org/nextui">
  <Card
    isPressable
    isHoverable
    variant="bordered"
    css={{ mw: "400px" }}
    href="https://github.com/nextui-org/nextui"
  >
    <Card.Header>First Button &rarr;</Card.Header>
    <Card.Body>Find in-depth information about Next.js features and API.</Card.Body>
  </Card>
</Link>
```

2. use `onClick` and `window.open` to open the link:

```
<Grid>
  <Card
   onClick={() => {
          window.open(""https://github.com/nextui-org/nextui"");
        }}
    isPressable
    isHoverable
    variant="bordered"
    css={{ mw: "400px" }}
  >
    <Card.Header>First Button &rarr;</Card.Header>
    <Card.Body>Find in-depth information about Next.js features and API.</Card.Body>
  </Card>
</Grid>
```